What is the frequency of a standing wave?
I understand that constructive interference of waves results in standing waves. And for a wire with both ends fixed the frequency should match the fundamental frequency of the wire to produce standing waves.
Now what I don't understand is,

What is harmonic? And what is overtone?

I know that amplitude of the particles varies with distance in standing waves, but I don't understand what my book meant when it states

"In finding the natural frequency of the wire in the sonometer, the paper piece placed on the wire is also at an anti-node if the wire is vibrating in its 3rd harmonic, although the amplitude will not be as large as it would be in the fundamental mode."

What relation does amplitudes and modes of vibration have?



which book? which page?

Harmonics visualization: https://youtu.be/PVX4V5Adbzk?feature=shared

I’m voting to close this question because it relies heavily on a quote from an unidentified source.

Also, the question is incomprehensible in is current form.  What does "the paper piece" mean?

A harmonic is a wave pattern formed by a standing wave. The first harmonic is the one with the longest wavelength(and lowest frequency), which decreases with higher harmonics. All harmonics have frequencies which are integral (whole number) multiples of the fundamental (i.e first) harmonic.
The term "overtone" means a harmonic frequency above the fundamental harmonic, as an example, the first overtone corresponds to the second harmonic and the fourth, fifth or sixth overtones correspond to the fifth, sixth and seventh harmonic respectively.
Sources:
Physics K.A Tsokos Sixth Edition Cambridge University Press 2014, page 184
Berg, Richard E.. "sound". Encyclopedia Britannica, 20 May. 2024, https://www.britannica.com/science/sound-physics. Accessed 20 July 2024.
Regarding your book, it would perhaps be more useful to show the diagram associated with it.
